# Is there a word for someone who tries to look like they are of high class or of high social status but fails miserably in a comical way?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for someone who tries to look like they are of high class or of high social status but fails miserably in a comical way?
Especially if they're of very low-class background. I looked it up but can't find anything.

I need that word to use in a paragraph that is describing a fictional character that I'm writing about.

Comment: A [poseur](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/poseur)?

Comment: @Weather Vane no but in a way where they genuinely believe it. like they  believe they are someone of high status and that everyone is worshipping them to a delusional extent.

Comment: You asked for a single word, two could be a *ridiculous poseur*.

Comment: The character is supposed to have severe delusions of grandeur and lack of touch with reality

Comment: Would "pretentious" fit?

Comment: Perhaps there is a fictional character who personifies what you want, for example a *Walter Mitty*, though I don't think that's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I have never heard of that character before but it definitely isn't what I'm looking for. "Mitty is a meek, mild man with a vivid fantasy life. In a few dozen paragraphs, he imagines himself a wartime pilot, an emergency-room surgeon, and a devil-may-care killer" My character is different in the way where their lack of touch from reality comes from severe neuroses and narcissism. They do not have a rich inner life, just a shell of a person controlled by neuroses and delusions.

Comment: I said it wasn't, it was an example of a character that became a well known description.

Comment: You might look at descriptions of a play by Moliere - "Le Bourgeois Gentilhomme" - to see if anything clicks.

Comment: Fop?  Someone who is concerned with clothes and appearance in an affected and excessive way; a dandy.

Comment: Wannabe.  This term is informal and applies to more than social class, but it expresses a common human inclination.

Comment: *dressed to the ones*, maybe? (a play on *dressed to the nines*)...

Comment: It might be relevant whether they're pretending to be an English aristocrat, to be middle class, or something else. Particularly if you're looking for stereotypical figures.

Comment: Your question and comments do not jibe. In the question you say "tries to look like" but in your comment you say "they genuinely believe" and that they are "delusional". I'll remove the downvote if you clarify the question.

Comment: The character is supposed to have narcissistic tendencies and obsession with gaining admiration from others, their delusions of them of being of high class doesn't stop them from actively trying to garner admiration from others. Their  persona is supposed to portray someone who is of unfortunate background who deeply denies being so. One who is wrapped up in their own lies.

Comment: And you want a noun, "He, who is in denial about his limitations and shortcomings, who believes that he is a great man who is universally admired, when just the opposite is true, is a _________".  You've used the word in your comment: narcissist.  If you want to stress how comical and ridiculous his behavior is, you could call him a buffoon.

Comment: So, is the posing related only to the trappings of wealth and status? Are you saying that the person is obviously not urbane and sophisticated, even though they're able to afford expensive clothing and jewelry, and that they constantly betray their humble origins and act oafishly?

Comment: The character is able to afford cheap clothing that tries to imitate expensive clothing. Their way of dressing is tacky and is supposed to look somewhat ridiculous. They marry someone who is somewhat upper middle class but having overestimated how much money they actually have and tend to spend money carelessly . They plunge into debt after a tragedy.

Comment: The details you are providing for your Gatsby-like character are rather inconsistent. From your descriptions, it's hard to know whether the person is simply living recklessly above their means and is something of a con-man, or is truly mad and delusional. If that ambiguity in the story is intentional, fine, but you can't ask us for a word if we can't tell which of the two is the truth.

Comment: Monsieur Jourdain, Le Bourgeois Gentilhomme.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia describes the fictional character [Hyacinth Bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyacinth_Bucket) in *Keeping Up Appearances* with (my emphasis)

> Hyacinth is a **social-climbing** snob who constantly aims to impress people, particularly of the upper and upper-middle classes, and to give the impression that she is of high social standing, despite her modest status.

with a quotation from the creator Roy Clarke

> So I knew my Hyacinths and I knew I had to write my own. They fascinated me. They were hilarious in their **pretensions**, so marvellously unaware of the real impressions they were making, and yet somehow so up front in their crusade to be superior that it was brave.

Comment: Yes, that is actually somewhat close, just lighter and less dark of a character. Charlotte Haze is another character more similar character but she isn't really an exact copy of my character, just a close resemblance of my character who is supposed to represent a mentally unsound mother with delusions of grandeur and controlling/psychotic tendencies.

Comment: A typical middle-class, middle-aged American woman, Charlotte Haze aspires to sophistication and European elegance, but her attempts fall comically flat. She is religious and not particularly imaginative. Charlotte sees Humbert as the epitome of the world-weary European lover of—and in—grand literature. He represents her chance to become the woman she dreams of being, but her vulgar, self-conscious stabs at sophistication, such as her tendency to drop celebrity names and mispronounce French phrases, make Humbert cringe.

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from Henry’s answer, I suggest another iconic British TV character - Del Boy from Only Fools and Horses. You could say :

> That guy is a bit of a Del Boy!

From Wikipedia

> From the sixth series on, he **adopts some of the mannerisms of a stereotypical yuppie of the late 1980s, pretending to be much more wealthy than he really is, as he tries to associate with the upper classes despite being obviously underclass.**
> ….
> Encompassing everything Cockney (though not an actual Cockney), Del Boy is known for his broken French phrases, which are usually completely out of context, and a variety of British and Cockney catchphrases, including: "He who dares, wins!", "This time next year we'll be millionaires", "Cushty!", "Lovely Jubbly!", "You know it makes sense" (which he usually says to his customers after they have agreed on a deal), "Shut up you tart" and "You plonker!", usually said to Rodney.